# openmp and armadillo on VS2015 compiller support for omp not detected

Tags: c++, openmp, armadillo

I have a c++ code in VS2015, in which I use armadillo 8.500.1. Today I tried to use openmp in a loop in the code as `#pragma omp parallel for` however when compilling the code I receive the following warning `"warning : use of OpenMP disabled; compiler support for OpenMP 3.1+ not detected"`

I have already selected Yes on project properties to enable openMP
I am using `#include <omp.h>`

Whenever I run my code compiled with openmp and armadillo it does not finish and get stuck (no error or anything). When I run the same code without the `#pragma omp parallel for` the code runs normally but in a single thread. I am pretty sure that it is some type of conflict.

looked around and could not find anything useful to solve it besides not using armadillo.

Comment: Visual Studio compiler only supports OpenMP 2.0, nothing newer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/parallel/openmp/openmp-in-visual-cpp?view=vs-2017

Comment: @UnholySheep would be possible to disable the armadillo openMP version to use only the intrinsic from visual studio?